# Instagram Basic Display API: Error Fetching Personal Account Details with "Unsupported request - method type: get"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-basic

I am currently working on integrating the Instagram Basic Display API into my application to fetch basic details from Instagram accounts. I have encountered an issue specifically when trying to retrieve details from my own personal Instagram account using the API. Below are the details of the problem I'm facing:

Issue Description:
When attempting to fetch basic details (such as username) from my personal Instagram account using the Instagram Basic Display API, I encounter the following error:
`{ "error": { "message": "Unsupported request - method type: get", "type": "IGApiException", "code": 100, "fbtrace_id": "ARiyap34pOXXS3JmDTOx-b_" } }`

Details:

- API Endpoint: https://graph.instagram.com/v19.0/me?fields=username&access_token=IGQ..... (access token truncated for privacy)
- HTTP Method: GET
- API Version: 19.0
- Error Message: "Unsupported request - method type: get"
- Error Type: IGApiException
- Error Code: 100
- Facebook Trace ID: ARiyap34pOXXS3JmDTOx-b_

Additional Information:

This issue occurs only when attempting to fetch details from my personal Instagram account. When using a creator or business account, the error does not occur.
I have verified that the access token used is valid and has the necessary permissions.
The documentation for the Instagram Basic Display API specifies that a GET request should be used to retrieve user details, which aligns with the method I'm using.
I have reviewed the documentation and ensured that I am following the correct steps and parameters for fetching user details.

Question:
What could be causing this "Unsupported request - method type: get" error when attempting to fetch details from my personal Instagram account using the Instagram Basic Display API? Is there any specific requirement or restriction for accessing personal account data through the API that I might be missing?

Comment: What happens when you use the user id you should have gotten from the token endpoint, instead of `me`?

Comment: Getting same error with user-id also.

https://graph.instagram.com/v19.0/68737......?fields=id,username&access_token=IGQW...